# mysql_real_escape_string in php, where to use it?

Tags: php, mysql

I just learned about the importance of `mysql_real_escape_string` to avoid MySQL injections. So i used this in my registration form in php. This is what i got,

```
$password_string = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PASSWORD']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['USERNAME']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FNAME']);
$mname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['MNAME']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['LNAME']);
```

Question: Do i also need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on forms that only verifies entries in the database? or is it only useful if you are inserting data into the database? I asked this because I also have a verification form wherein users will input data to see if those records exist in the database. Do i still need the `mysql_real_escape_string` for security?

Thanks!

Comment: use it when you are taking inputs from user , don't trust user inputs

Comment: first of all stop using `mysql_*`, it's officially deprecated library. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. and regarding your question use it when you got user input.apply on them.

Comment: Prepared Statements are much more secure and up to date than mysql_* ...

Comment: its kinda weird.. i tried using mysqli but didnt work. i'm running PHP 5.5.24. in my code, i'm using mysql. will there be an issue if I use both mysql and mysqli in one php file?

Comment: you cannot mix both.go for `mysqli` or `PDO` fully and completely.

Answer (score 2):

In general you have to take care of all strings you somehow inject into a sql statement if those string are not literally defined and totally under your control. Simplified you could say everything that comes from the client side, regardless if it was visible there or hidden, whether it was an input field or some other means of interaction. *Everything* can have been changed or manipulated on the client side. So never trust anything you receive from there.

It even does make sense to also handle certain strings originating form the server side. Or, obviously, from other data sources like remote systems you retrieve data from, files you read or, *yes*, your own database entries you just read.

The only things that can be considered save are constant values like literal strings, numbers, defines. But even here you have to take care that they do not contain any characters with special meaning in sql. So if in doubt, then escape.

---

That said...

the old php `mysql` extension you use ("the `mysql` functions") has been deprecated long ago. It should not be used any more. Please consider porting your code the the newer `mysqli` extension or to `PDO`. Both offer better protection by means of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding". Both alternatives have a great documentation on the web and you can find many many tutorials and examples for their usage.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is used to escape special characters from the data, (that are likely to break the query) before executing the query. It should be used with `SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE, DELETE` .

Suppose while you are selecting a data from database : `SELECT * from table WHERE id='1' and instead of 1` we have " 1' " , this would break your query. : `SELECT * from table WHERE id='1''`

Also `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated in new version of PHP , use `mysqli` and try `PDO` instead.

Comment: its kinda weird.. i tried using mysqli but didnt work. i'm running PHP 5.5.24. in my code, i'm using mysql. will there be an issue if I use both mysql and mysqli in one php file?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated in PHP Ver >= 5.5.0 . Stay with just 1 i.e mysqli, 
As mysql_real_escape_string Its not removed from PHP 5 yet it seems to be working . But avoid using it. 

If you use mysqli_real_escape_string, You should open the mysql connection with mysqi : refer : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: dont use both mysql and mysqli in single application. thoese are different "standard" ways to access mysql - do not mix them. mysql-real-eacape... is mysql function. in mysqli there is different way to do same job. if possible, use pdo. if not prefer mysqli. mysql-xxx itself are deprecated, but i do not see them to go away any time soon